# Using TimeUnit to sleep in between changing JavaFX Label text

Tags: java, javafx, sleep

I'm writing a GUI in JavaFX for a Pokemon game I've been working on. After I click what move I want to use, I want to narrate the attack with a label. There are several messages I want to display separately, so I'm trying to use TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep() to put a 3-second gap in between each message. When I run the program, it stays on the previous screen (moveOptions in the code), waits 6 seconds and resets to the main screen (battleOptions) without displaying any messages. Why won't it display my labels?

```
@FXML
HBox battleOptions, moveOptions, attackNarration;

@FXML
Label narration;

public void handleMoveButton() throws InterruptedException {

        this.moveOptions.setVisible(false);                  //makes previous screen invisible
        this.attackNarration.setVisible(true);               //makes the layout containing my messages visible

        this.narration.setText("Pikachu used Tackle");       
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);                           //should display above message for 3 seconds

        this.narration.setText("Foe Pikachu used Tackle");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);                           //should change to this message for 3 seconds

        this.attackNarration.setVisible(false);              //makes message screen invisible
        this.battleOptions.setVisible(true);                 //makes home screen visible to restart the turn
    }
```

Comment: I think this could be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html

Comment: You cannot use sleep.  JavaFX runs on a single thread, and your sleep calls will hold up that thread—preventing JavaFX from doing any redrawing or processing of user input during the sleep duration.  As aran suggested, the javafx.animation package is what you should use.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working with a Timeline.

Comment: hey, glad it helped